# Handling nested keys that don't exist using .get()

Tags: python, nested, key

I am having an issue trying to solve this issue. I am trying to get data out from a dict created from the sample data below. For each record I am putting the values into variables. My problem is that if the key does not exist I get None returned...which is ok, however if I the try to get data from a level below the first missing key I get an error. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

My data set has lots of records and not all records have all the keys, so I need a way to handle missing data.

If I change the error line from:

```
cat_breeds = pets.get(uid).get('Info').get('Cats').get('Breeds')
```

to

```
cat_breeds = pets.get(uid).get('Info').get('Cats', {}).get('Breeds', {})
```

the code works without an error, but the result is `{}` and that causes problems down the road when inserting into mysql.

I have not been able to find a solution for this.

Code

```
# pip install git+https://github.com/SirAnthony/slpp
from slpp import slpp as lua

def get_pets(uid):
    animal =pets.get(uid).get('Info')
    cats = pets.get(uid).get('Info').get('Cats')
    cat_breeds = pets.get(uid).get('Info').get('Cats').get('Breeds')
    dogs = pets.get(uid).get('Info').get('Dogs')


    return animal, cats, dogs, cat_breeds

file = open("data2.lua")
data = file.read()
file.close()
d1 = data.split('test =')[1]

pets = lua.decode(d1)
for key, value in pets.items():
    uid = key
    print(uid)

    for k, v in pets[uid]['Info'].items():
        animal, cats, dogs, cat_breeds = get_pets(uid)
        print(animal)
        print(cats)
        print(cat_breeds)
        print(dogs)
```

Sample Data

```
test =
{
   ["e81b882c2963930"] =
    {
        ["Info"] =
        {
            ["Dogs"] =
            {
                ["Breeds"] =
                {
            ["Bull Dog"] =
            {
                ["Bruiser"] = 5,
                ["Bowser"] = 3,
            }, -- end of ["Bull Dogs"]
            ["Husky"] =
            {
                ["Cujo"] = 7,
            }, -- end of ["Husky"]
                    }, -- end of ["Breed"]
                }, -- end of ["Dogs"]
            }, -- end of ["Pets"]
        }, -- end of ["Info"]
    }, -- end of ["e81b882c2963930"]

    } -- end of test
```

Comment: If the `dict` doesn't have the key specified you could return an empty `dict` instead of `None`. Like this: `{'a': 123}.get('b', {}).get('c', {})`.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above I have done that. The problem is that it creates problems down the line when I insert the data into a mysql database. I could probably do something to solve that issue, but I figured there must be a better way than how I am doing it.

Comment: What problems? You can change the default value of the last `get` in the chain to something other than `{}`, or you can explicitly test if `cat_breeds` is a problematic value later.

Comment: I thought I had tried this, but in retrospect I think I put default values in every Key and not just the last key and that caused the problem. I went back and put ```{}``` as the default value for everything leading up to the last key and then a default value for the key I was after and that appears to work as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the sanest way of dealing with this is just to have it throw `KeyError`s, and catch that error:

```
def get_pets(uid):
    try:
        animal = pets[uid]['Info']
        cats = animal['Cats']
        cat_breeds = cats['Breeds']
        dogs = animal['Dogs']
        return animal, cats, dogs, cat_breeds
    except KeyError:
        return None  # Or some other error-indicating value
```

And then at the call-site, you can check for errors:

```
for k, v in pets[uid]['Info'].items():
    returned = get_pets(uid)

    if returned is None:
        print(f"Error for {k} {v}")
    else:
        animal, cats, dogs, cat_breeds = returned
        print(animal)
        print(cats)
        print(cat_breeds)
        print(dogs)
```

That loops seems off though. Why loop over `items()`, but then never use `k` or `v`? It seems like you can just get rid of the loop:

```
returned = get_pets(uid)

if returned is None:
    print(f"Error for {uid}")
else:
    animal, cats, dogs, cat_breeds = returned
    print(animal)
    print(cats)
    print(cat_breeds)
    print(dogs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have a look at implementing the suggestion and see if I can get it to work. As for as the loop goes, maybe I need to rethink what I am doing there...

Comment: @XenPanda For the loops, it just seems odd that the function only requires `uid`, but you're looping over the same data multiple times. It seems like you can just simply get rid of the loop.